# access data returned from a method of a class in other methods

Tags: matlab, class, methods

I've got the following class

```
classdef setting
        
    properties(Constant)
        n = setting.get_n;
        q = setting.get_q;
    end
    
    methods(Static)
        function data = load_setting
            File = 'Configuration.ini';
            I = INI('File',File);
            I.read();
            data = I.get('UserData'); % struct
        end
        
        function n = get_n
            data = setting.load_setting;
            n = data.m + 2;
        end

        function q = get_q
            data = setting.load_setting;
            temp = data.q;
            q           = fieldnames(temp);        
        end
    end
end
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to access `data` returned by `load_setting` automatically in the rest of the methods defined in the class instead of calling it `data = load_setting`  in each method. Suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: Is `data` updated more than once? If not you could just move the `load_setting` call inside the class constructor

Comment: If the data is unchanging, you could even make `data` a static variable and re-use it rather than reading it in every time you need it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, data doesn't change. Could you please show an example? I'm not sure if I understand how to set `data` as a static variabe

Comment: @MatteoV Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please show how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants are typically provided by functions in MATLAB. For example, `pi` is a function. A function that provides constant data that is read from a file could be written like this, using the keyword [`persistent`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) (code not tested):

```matlab
function data = config_data
   persistent data;
   if isempty(data)
      File = 'Configuration.ini';
      I = INI('File',File);
      I.read();
      data = I.get('UserData');
   end
end
```

Now the first time you use `config_data`, it will load the data. Subsequent times it will immediately return the data struct. In the most recent version of MATLAB you can use dot indexing on the return value of a function, so you can do `config_data().m` or `config_data().q` and get the relevant field from your data. The function above could process the data further to obtain the `q` and `n` values that are computed in your static class methods, so you don't need anything from the `setting` class, as long as all the data is static.

If you need your constant data to be a class instead of a function (static methods computing values on the fly, or using input values), I would plug the above into your class as the static function `load_setting`, because that leads to the least amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to create a Constant property which you can change it! its through class composition.
first you should define a data class of reference(handle) type :

```
classdef dataclass<handle
    properties
        m=3;
        n=4;
    end
end
```

then create a Constant data property in your setting class :

```
classdef setting
    properties (Constant)
        data=dataclass()
    end
    methods (Static)
        function somefunc()
            a=setting();
            a.data.n=1;
            a.data.m=2;
        end
        function out=showdata()
            out=setting.data;
        end
    end
end
```

this way you have a constant reference to the data and when you call A.somefunc() you can change it within all class and all objects of that class.